# Некорректное отображение русского языка emacs/spacemacs

Tags: локализация, emacs

Русский шрифт в spacemacse отображается относительно большим и с большим межбуквенным расстояние.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это исправить? Не смог найти в документации spacemacs-а, как откорректировать это, или пропустил.